# Javascript `onblur` event cascades the `Id` of the `html` input element

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript `onblur` event cascades the `Id` of the `html` input element on to the preceding input elements rather than passing the `id` of their own onblurred element.

```js
var ruleStringParam = {
     ruleset : "",
     appid : "",
     rule : "",
     trigger : {name : "", type : "", timerparams : {repeatEvery : "", scheduleDate : "", scheduleTime : "", expiryDateTime : ""}, 
      state : "", device : "", transit : "", range : ""},
     condition : {statement : ""},
     action : {type : "", subject : "", object : ""}
    }
    
var buildRuleJSON = function(elementId) { 
    switch (elementId) {
    case 'ruleset':
      ruleStringParam.ruleset = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
      alert('Id of ruleset: ' + elementId); 
    case 'appId':
      ruleStringParam.appId = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
      alert('Id of appId ' + elementId);
    case 'rule':
      ruleStringParam.rule = document.getElementById(elementId).value; 
      alert('Id of rule ' + elementId);
    default:
      alert("default");
    }
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <form id="form1" name="form1">
    Ruleset name:<br>
    <input id='ruleset' type='text' onblur="buildRuleJSON(this.id)"><br>
    AppId:<br>
    <input id='appId' type='text' onblur='buildRuleJSON(this.id)'><br>
    Rule name:<br>
    <input id='rule' type='text' onblur='buildRuleJSON(this.id)'><br>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: When one correct your initial code in your question, without any comment, your question became invalid(!), because with the corrected code, there is no problem you describe. So, the actual (corrected) code in your question works. It is same code as in the accepted answer! Code-Correction should be reverted.

Comment: in other words: The code from the accepted answer is **identical** to the code in your question. How can the accepted answer (with no code differences) be a solution to your problem? Further: the accepted answer is **wrong**, because you don't forget/miss a **break** in your code.

Comment: @Ben I am not sure how my incorrect code in the question got edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to break out of your cases:**

When you write a switch statement, the execution continues if you don't `break` out:

```
switch (elementId) {
    case 'ruleset':
        ruleStringParam.ruleset = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
        alert('Id of ruleset: ' + elementId); 
        break;
    case 'appId':
        ruleStringParam.appId = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
        alert('Id of appId ' + elementId);
        break;
    case 'rule':
        ruleStringParam.rule = document.getElementById(elementId).value;    
        alert('Id of rule ' + elementId);
        break;
    default:
        alert("default");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you blur input field A by clicking into input field B, then B receives the focus.

But since you are firing an `alert`, that focus is taken away from B when that alert is shown, so that the blur handler for B fires ...

Don’t use `alert` here. If you need to make debug outputs to retrace what exactly your script is doing when, then use `console.log` instead, and check the browser console.